# obtener valor de un input oculto y enviarlo al controller

Tags: php, laravel

actualmente tengo el siguiente campo

```
     <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="precio">Precio</label>
          <input type="number" disabled name="precioprueba" id="precio"
          class="form-control" style="visibility:hidden placeholder="*Precio..>
       </div>
     </div>
```

El mismo debe estar oculto al usuario, pero almacenar su valor en el método en donde guardo los datos recibidos del formulario, pero al tratar de hacer clic en guardar viaja vacío alguien me puede decir como hago para ocultarlo pero que se guarde su valor

Comment: Gracias lo pruebo y comento, saludos

Comment: Gracias me fue de diez, miles de gracias

Comment: cómo se hace para colocarla como respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente lo solucioné de la siguiente forma

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="precio">Precio</label>
      <input type="hidden" id="precio"
      class="form-control" style="visibility:hidden placeholder="*Precio..>
   </div>
 </div>
```